# How to decide where Ember.js is rendered?

Tags: ember.js

I have a application created with Ember.js. The html has script tags. I want to place pure HTML div below the content rendered by Ember.js. But when i place it below like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
</script>
<div>my super div</div>
```

The super div is above the ember.js content. What to do so it will be below the ember.js content?

Comment: Why not place it under the `{{outlet}}` in your `application.hbs` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `app/templates/application.hbs` file is an Ember's primary template file. The `{{outlet}}` allows any route templates to get rendered in that template. You can place your `<div>` below the `{{outlet}}` to have the `application.hbs` file render it:

```
<h1>tomaszs's app</h1>
  {{outlet}}
<div>my super div</div>
```

This way, your `<div>` will appear "below" the Ember content (which is rendered through `{{outlet}}`).

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to place the div under the `{{outlet}}` of the parent template. for example if your router looks like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

and you want this functionality in the `posts/new` template you need to place the div tag under the `{{outlet}}` in the posts template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div in your html with an id of say "foo" then in your ember config, use the `rootElement` prop (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement) and your ember application will always render into that div. Now in your static html, it will respect the source ordering.